# Add new line when button press

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to add a new line for every command-button-press, however, right now I am only getting  to edit up and until row 2.

```
     Dim booConfirmation As Boolean
      'Check for data
    
     
      booConfirmation = MsgBox("Are you sure the entries are correct?", vbYesNo)
    
    If booConfirmation = vbNo Then
        MsgBox "Please edit your entries"
        Exit Sub
       
Else
        Set WS = Sheets("Calculator")
        lastrow = WS.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'I think this is the problem
    
        WS.Range("B" & lastrow).Value = ComboBox1.Text                              'Adds the TextBox1 into Col B & Last Blank Row
        WS.Range("C" & lastrow).Value = TextBox16.Text                              'Adds the TextBox2 into Col C & Last Blank Row
        WS.Range("D" & lastrow).Value = ComboBox3.Text                              'Adds the TextBox3 into Col D & Last Blank Row
```

Comment: I think you'll need to check column B for the last row.  COlumn A doesnt get anything added?

Comment: `Dim booConfirmation as Boolean` ---> `Dim confirmation As VbMsgBoxResult`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
lastrow = ws.Range("A:E").Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row+1
```